# FCM setBackgroundMessageHandler not running on ios background or quit state only

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to set up FCM on an expo app

Environement information :-

```
expo-cli - v6.0.8
@react-native-firebase/app - v14
@react-native-firebase/messaging - v14
@notifee/react-native - v7.4.0
```

ios 16 - testing on real device

in App.tsx I use the following code. remember that expo structure is different than react-native but putting setBackgroundMessageHandler outside of the app component is the right place.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

import messaging from "@react-native-firebase/messaging";
import notifee from "@notifee/react-native";
import Clipboard from '@react-native-clipboard/clipboard';

// #9286F8 PECUNIA CHANGES
notifee.onBackgroundEvent(async (event) => {
  console.log("Forsa-App >> root app notifee onBackgroundEvent", event.type);
});

// #9286F8 PECUNIA CHANGES
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
  console.log("My-App >> setBackgroundMessageHandler >> remoteMessage ", remoteMessage);

  let result: any = {
    messageID: remoteMessage.messageId,
    title: remoteMessage?.data?.title,
    content: remoteMessage?.data?.content,
    extras: remoteMessage?.data?.extras ? JSON.parse(remoteMessage?.data?.extras) : null,
    notificationEventType: remoteMessage?.data?.notificationEventType,
    badge: remoteMessage?.data?.badge,
    ring: remoteMessage?.data?.ring,
  };

  Object.keys(result).forEach((key) => !result[key] && delete result[key]);

  const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
    id: "default",
    name: "default",
  });

  // Display a notification
  let displayData: any = {
    title: result.title,
    content: result.content,
    extras: result.extras,
    notificationEventType: result.notificationEventType,
    badge: result.badge,
    ring: result.ring,
  };

  Object.keys(displayData).forEach((key) => !displayData[key] && delete displayData[key]);

  await notifee.displayNotification({
    title: result.title,
    body: result.content,
    data: displayData,
    android: {
      channelId,
      smallIcon: "ic_launcher", // optional, defaults to 'ic_launcher'.
      // pressAction is needed if you want the notification to open the app when pressed
      pressAction: {
        launchActivity: "default",
        id: "default",
      },
    },
  });
});

export default function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await messaging().requestPermission({
        alert: true,
        provisional: true,
        criticalAlert: true,
      });

      let registerID = await messaging().getToken();

      setToken(registerID);

      const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {
        Alert.alert("A new FCM message arrived!", JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
        console.log("My-App >> onMessage >> remoteMessage ", remoteMessage);

        let result: any = {
          messageID: remoteMessage.messageId,
          title: remoteMessage?.data?.title,
          content: remoteMessage?.data?.content,
          extras: remoteMessage?.data?.extras ? JSON.parse(remoteMessage?.data?.extras) : null,
          notificationEventType: remoteMessage?.data?.notificationEventType,
          badge: remoteMessage?.data?.badge,
          ring: remoteMessage?.data?.ring,
        };

        Object.keys(result).forEach((key) => !result[key] && delete result[key]);

        const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
          id: "default",
          name: "default",
        });

        // Display a notification
        let displayData: any = {
          title: result.title,
          content: result.content,
          extras: result.extras,
          notificationEventType: result.notificationEventType,
          badge: result.badge,
          ring: result.ring,
        };

        Object.keys(displayData).forEach((key) => !displayData[key] && delete displayData[key]);

        await notifee.displayNotification({
          title: result.title,
          body: result.content,
          data: displayData,
          android: {
            channelId,
            smallIcon: "ic_launcher", // optional, defaults to 'ic_launcher'.
            // pressAction is needed if you want the notification to open the app when pressed
            pressAction: {
              launchActivity: "default",
              id: "default",
            },
          },
        });
      });

      return unsubscribe;
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.tsx to start working on your app!</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Clipboard.setString(token)}>
        <Text>Token: {token}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <StatusBar style='auto' />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

Now As you can see setBackgroundMessageHandler method is outside of the app component

Now I send notification from server-backend using this library `firebase-admin`

```
import firbaseAdmin from 'firebase-admin';

let result = await firbaseAdmin.messaging().sendToDevice(
  registrationTokens,
  {
    data,
    // notification: {
    //   title: 'test',
    //   body: 'test',
    // },
  },
  {
    // Required for background/quit data-only messages on iOS
    contentAvailable: true,
    // Required for background/quit data-only messages on Android
    priority: "high",
  }
);

console.log("result", result);
```

As you can see I commented notification in payload, because FCM sdk will handle the notification automaticllay if I add it. And I checked when I uncomment the notification background and foreground notification works on ios, but of course click events doesn't work when application is opened. So I wanted to handle the notification manually because it will be used in other methods before displaying it to the user using notifee.

I also checked that APNs is correctly installed by using

```
let apnToken = await messaging().getAPNSToken();
```

This will give me ios apnsToken and I used to send messages to the ios device using `apn` lib and it works.

What I don't understand is that,

why setBackgroundMessageHandler is not being triggered when IOS app is in background or quit state, but works on android and on ios when app is in foreground ?